# Fbx exported file is different to .blend when imported in Unity

Tags: mesh, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, unity, .fbx

I encountered a weird issue today. When I exported my model as `fbx` and imported it, I noticed the meshes were different to the `.blend` import. For example there was a hole in my character's head. I went back to check normal and they were all fine. How do I check what is causing this issue and results in different meshes from `.blend` and `.fbx` formats?

It is also interesting to note `fbx` actually keeps all the animations however `.blend` removed a lot of small animations from my model. Is this normal?